# Best Approach to Refresh a Class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Simply i want to know what is the Best Approach to refresh a class.Like when same class is used from diff-diff section of application where we pass some data to that class ,I can do it by simply taking a global variable and change it's value from other class's But i want to know some another approach which is best suitable for this kind of Things.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this kind of structure, where the class needs to be effectively shared between other MVCs, is to make the class a singleton. This means that only one instance of a class is ever used. That way if one MVC changes the class you don't need to sync the change because every MVC uses the same instance.

To make a class a singleton you do the following

Create a static var which is an instance of the class

Make the init function private so no other class can initialise it

Eg

```
class Singleton {

    static var shared = Singleton()

    var info = "singleton info variable"

    private init() {}

    func doSomething() {}

}
```

To access the class you do the following

```
Singleton.shared.doSomething()
```

or

```
let singletonInfo = Singleton.shared.info
```

Comment: i want to know to refresh  a class when that class access by other class's.

Comment: did i need to took a global variable in that class and set it's value from other class's and compare it to perform specific task.

Comment: Yeah this will do that. It's effectively a global class, so if you change info in your Singleton class every class that accesses Singleton will see the updated value for info

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question clearly, with this you don't need to refresh anything because everything is in sync anyways.

Comment: If you have a singleton you don't need to pass anything along or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

(Simplified) - Either you create a new instance and pass it on:

```
class MyClass {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myClass = MyClass(name: "Hello World")

    func actionThatCausesSegue() {
       let copyOfMyClass = MyClass(name: self.myClass.name)
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "MySegue", sender: copyOfMyClass)
    }
}
```

Or you can use structs:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myStruct = MyStruct(name: "Hello World")

    func actionThatCausesSegue() {
       // structs are always copied when passed around.
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "MySegue", sender: self.myStruct)
    }
}
```

Structs are always copied, when you pass them around. Here's the explanation from the Swift Programming Language Guide by Apple:

> Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types
>
> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a
>   variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.
>
> You’ve actually been using value types extensively throughout the
>   previous chapters. In fact, all of the basic types in Swift—integers,
>   floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, arrays and dictionaries—are
>   value types, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.
>
> All **structures** and enumerations are value types in Swift.

You can read more about the differences [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation, but I sometimes do this for views in iOS. For example when the data model changes you want the view to update, so I implement a method in the controller called `configureThingyViewWithThingy` which takes the new 'thingy' and updates the view. Then whatever mechanism you're using to monitor data model changes (KVO, notifications, etc.) will call this method to reconfigure the view with the new data.

Comment: ok i give you the situation,when user access a same class A from 3 other different classes .At that time api hits that depend upon from which class you  are accessing this current class A.At that time did i need to compare a global variable  OR do i need something else.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. It's not clear if you have one instance or three instances of the same class. I don't know if this confusion comes from a language barrier, or misunderstanding technical terminology. If you have someone who speaks good English as well as your native language, and also understands the technical terms being used, get them to help with asking questions, to get better answers on SO. Sorry to not be much help, keep learning :)